# How to effectively merge Spark output files on EMR?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark

Spark jobs (I think) create a file for each partition so that it can handle for failures, etc..., so at the end of the job you are left with a folder that can have a lot of folders left in them.  These are being automatically loaded to S3, so is there a way to merge them into a single compressed file that is ready for loading to Redshift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the following, which will write one uncompressed file per partition in "my_rdd"...

```
my_rdd.saveAsTextFile(destination)
```

One could do...

```
my_rdd.repartition(1).saveAsTextFile(destination, compressionCodecClass=“org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec”)
```

This sends the data in all partitions to one particular worker node in the cluster to be combined into one massive partition, which will then be written out into a single gzip compressed file.

However, I don't believe this is a desirable solution to the problem.  Just one thread writes out and compresses the single result file.  If that file is huge, that could take "forever".  Every core in the cluster sits idle but one.  Redshift doesn't need everything to be in a single file.  Redshift can easily handle loading a set of files --- use COPY with a "manifest file" or a "prefix":  [Using the COPY Command to Load from S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_loading-tables-from-s3.html).